# barryvdh/laravel-debugbar won't allow method calls in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen

I'm using Lumen 5.5.2, and the latest version of the laravel-debugbar package I installed via Composer.

I made the necessary changes to these files, as specified in the manual.

`app/bootstrap/app.php`:

```
+ $app->register(Barryvdh\Debugbar\LumenServiceProvider::class);
+ $app->configure('debugbar');
```

`app/config/app.php`

```
+ 'aliases' => ['Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class]
```

The bar displays fine, but I ran into an issue of not being able to call any methods mentioned in the manual. For example, when I try to report exceptions, using this code in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    \Debugbar::addException($e);
    parent::report($e);
}
```

I get the following uncaught error: Class 'Debugbar' not found in /home/vagrant/code/lumen/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 37.

Considering I registered the alias within my app config, I'm puzzled why Lumen is unable to get the class.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution on my own, provided you've set everything up properly, it's possible to set `$var = app('debugbar');`, and then call methods relative to `$var`, ex.: `$var->info('Logging info...')`.

I'm still curious if there is a better solution.